# Debian: Order of DNS servers when using VPN

Tags: debian, dns, vpn

My notebook gets its DNS servers via DHCP.

When I start a VPN session (pptp, managed my networkmanager), the DNS servers received from that VPN session are queried first.

I'd like to use the DNS servers of the VPN only if my primary DNS returns NXDOMAIN.

How do I do that?

#### /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain homesweethome
search homesweethome
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

#### traceroute 8.8.8.8 when connected to VPN

```
 1  sheldon.homesweethome (192.168.1.1)  0.714 ms  0.880 ms  1.001 ms
 2  * * *
 3  172.30.12.49 (172.30.12.49)  13.693 ms  14.181 ms  14.316 ms
 4  84.116.191.49 (84.116.191.49)  15.067 ms  15.199 ms  15.336 ms
 5  * * *
 6  216.239.56.106 (216.239.56.106)  22.409 ms  14.401 ms  14.447 ms
 7  216.239.57.192 (216.239.57.192)  14.414 ms 216.239.57.188 (216.239.57.188)  22.950 ms 216.239.57.127 (216.239.57.127)  22.846 ms
 8  66.249.95.23 (66.249.95.23)  22.992 ms 66.249.95.39 (66.249.95.39)  23.832 ms 209.85.253.216 (209.85.253.216)  23.556 ms
 9  74.125.37.150 (74.125.37.150)  28.828 ms  28.571 ms  24.278 ms
10  209.85.246.160 (209.85.246.160)  21.975 ms 216.239.42.98 (216.239.42.98)  21.467 ms 216.239.51.207 (216.239.51.207)  23.297 ms
11  * * *
12  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  22.556 ms  23.421 ms  23.266 ms
```

#### traceroute 8.8.8.8 when not connected

```
 1  sheldon.homesweethome (192.168.1.1)  0.651 ms  3.098 ms  4.927 ms
 2  * * *
 3  172.30.12.49 (172.30.12.49)  16.504 ms  16.791 ms  17.125 ms
 4  84.116.191.49 (84.116.191.49)  17.186 ms  23.111 ms  23.277 ms
 5  * * *
 6  216.239.56.22 (216.239.56.22)  25.766 ms 216.239.56.178 (216.239.56.178)  17.433 ms 216.239.56.22 (216.239.56.22)  18.432 ms
 7  216.239.57.182 (216.239.57.182)  17.526 ms  14.840 ms 216.239.57.190 (216.239.57.190)  15.748 ms
 8  209.85.253.216 (209.85.253.216)  17.661 ms 66.249.95.39 (66.249.95.39)  17.786 ms  18.213 ms
 9  74.125.37.154 (74.125.37.154)  29.039 ms 74.125.37.103 (74.125.37.103)  28.667 ms 74.125.37.97 (74.125.37.97)  25.168 ms
10  209.85.250.165 (209.85.250.165)  25.532 ms  24.350 ms 216.239.51.149 (216.239.51.149)  25.776 ms
11  * * *
12  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  22.513 ms  22.979 ms  22.484 ms
```

#### /etc/ppp/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 10.11.10.101
nameserver 10.11.10.102
```

Comment: VPN...primary VPN...some mix up? Is your VPN using split tunneling or not? What kind of VPN? openvpn or ipsec? what vendor?

Comment: corrected, thank you. `primary VPN` -> `primary DNS`. Added type of VPN.

Comment: Thank you. please add to the post, when inside the VPN: a traceroute to www.google.com/8.8.8.8, and your /etc/resolv.conf/your active DNS servers inside the VPN

Comment: are you able do do an nslookup to an internal DNS server while inside the VPN?

Comment: When connected to the VPN, I can query it and it resolves correctly everything it "knows" about, i.e. everything that's internal to its network. When inside the VPN and asking for something "external", it fails and uses my DNS that's set in /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: i got lost. It seems you have connectivity to the outside, however no DNS, right? What should be your normal DNS be outside the VPN? it should be 192.168.1.1, right? IMO it is a matter of adding it to /etc/ppp/resolv.conf as one quick fix.

Comment: does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf ` helps?

Comment: Youre correct, I didn't see the obvious: Adding my main DNS to /etc/ppp/resolv.conf fixed the issue. If you put that as an answer I'd happily accept that. Do you also have a more generic approach in case my main DNS changes because I'm traveling?

Comment: Are all of the internal names under one or a few domains? I.e., could you say "use the external servers for everything, except `*.internal.foo.com` and `*.secret.bar.com`"? (This is easy to configure with dnsmasq).

Comment: derobert beat me to dnsmasq while I was editing the answer. I am afraid I use a IPsec VPN with strongswan+BIND, and I am not a much more help than pointing out a related link in my answer. Btw, IPsec is much more secure than PPTP. As a bonus, I implement IPsec as compatible with the actual native IPsec clients of OS/X and iPhone. I actually intercept DNS requests, and I completely replace whichever DNS server the client is using for name solving, performance, and security reasons. If in a hostile network/public wifi I am quite sure I do not want to use their DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access for internal resources when having a active VPN connection is only supposed to work if you have Split Tunneling active.

[Split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling)

> Split tunneling is a computer networking concept which allows a mobile
>   user to access dissimilar security domains like a public network
>   (e.g., the Internet) and a local LAN or WAN at the same time, using
>   the same or different network connections.

With split tunneling, it is then a matter of the DNS order server having the DNS of the VPN at the top and your normal DNS servers at the end. By the normal inner workings of DNS, the top ones failing the request will trickle down to the bottom ones.

You seem to have already split tunnelling active per our debugging, so as a quick fix, it is a matter of adding your DNS to `/etc/ppp/resolv.conf`.

As for having a more generic approach, this page talks about using dnsmasq.

[DNS routing after PPTP connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640172/dns-routing-after-pptp-connection)

> A solution would be to run a local DNS server that can forward queries
>   to other DNS servers based on subdomain/domain.
>
> Ubuntu's network-manager already runs a local DNS server
>   (dnsmasq-base) however the required options are not available so
>   disable it then install and configure the full dnsmasq package as
>   follows:
>
> 1) Comment out dns=dnsmasq from /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
>   2) Restart network-manager: sudo service network-manager restart
>   3) Install dnsmasq package: sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
>   4) Edit /etc/dnsmasq.conf and add:
>   address=/.mywork/VPN_DNS_IP address=/#/INTERNET_DNS_IP
>   5) Restart
>   dnsmaq: sudo service dnsmasq restart

I will also leave here a link concerning security with VPN protocols.

[PPTP VS L2TP/IPSEC VS OPENVPN](https://www.ivpn.net/pptp-vs-l2tp-vs-openvpn)

> The Microsoft implementation of PPTP has serious security
>   vulnerabilities. MSCHAP-v2 is vulnerable to dictionary attack and the
>   RC4 algorithm is subject to a bit-flipping attack. Microsoft strongly
>   recommends upgrading to IPSec where confidentiality is a concern.

Comment: I will also add this one: https://nohats.ca/wordpress/blog/2014/12/29/dont-stop-using-ipsec-just-yet/